# Why doesn't this very basic JQuery autocomplete work when using a local array of objects?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, object, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

When I use a simple local array I have no problems.  I have no problems populating that array from MySQL, too.  But when I try to load an array of object, even a local array, it doesn't work.  What am I missing?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
    <input id="autocomplete">
    <script>
    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: [ { label:"c++", value=1 }, { label: "java", value=2 }, { label: "javascript", value=3 } ]
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your syntax for defining property values for an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) is incorrect:

```
[ 
    { 
        label:"c++", 
        value: 1 /* Be sure to use ":" and not "=" here */
    } 
]
```

Use `:` instead of `=`.

A tool like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) will help you find simple errors like this.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/92Qjw/

Comment: Thanks very much.  I have a related question, but made it a separate question.